# Curl Failed: Failed to connect to [servername] port 8072: Connection timed out

Tags: php, curl

I am using PHP cURL to get the response back from the api (112.133.209.131:8072) with GET request. When i run the code in localhost. Everything runs perfect(response is obtained) but the same code does not work from the live server.

Comment: curl extension or curl ssl certificate is not installed on live server

Comment: sorry, there is connection timed out, possibly your IP black listed on target server. Try to use proxy.